# How to combine ant-design checkbox and table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, antd

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: Table]

It is filled from the `data` array. As you can see in this object there is a `done` field. I want to make the `check-boxes` marked depending on the value of the `done` field. And of course I want the checkbox value to change the field value in the object.

Here's my code:

```
<template>
  <a-table :columns="columns" :dataSource="data">
    <span slot="action">
      <a-checkbox :checked="checked" @click="onChange"> </a-checkbox>
    </span>
  </a-table>
</template>

<script>
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Student",
    dataIndex: "Student",
    key: "Student"
  },
  {
    title: "Action",
    key: "action",
    width: "1%",
    scopedSlots: { customRender: "action" }
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    Student: "John Brown",
    done: false
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    Student: "John Brown",
    done: true
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    Student: "John Brown",
    done: false
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    Student: "John Brown",
    done: true
  }
];

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data,
      columns,
      checked: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(e) {
      this.checked = e.target.checked;
    },
    toggleChecked() {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Ant Table](https://www.antdv.com/components/table/), you need to use `slot-scope="text, record"` to biding the value in `<a-checkbox >`. Like below

```
<a-checkbox :checked="record.done" @click="onChange(record)"></a-checkbox>
```

You can check here with working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-with-custom-checkbox-zc8io) example.

---

**Code Snippet**

```html
<template>
  <a-table :columns="columns" :dataSource="data">
    <span slot="action" slot-scope="record">
      <a-checkbox :checked="record.done" @click="onChange(record)"></a-checkbox>
    </span>
  </a-table>
</template>

<script>
const columns = [{
    title: "Student",
    dataIndex: "Student",
    key: "Student"
  },{
    title: "Action",
    key: "action",
    width: "1%",
    scopedSlots: { customRender: "action" }
  }],
  data = [
  { key: "1", Student: "John Brown", done: false },
  { key: "2", Student: "John Brown", done: true },
  { key: "3", Student: "John Brown", done: false },
  { key: "4", Student: "John Brown", done: true }
];

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      data,
      columns
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(record) {
      record.done = !record.done;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```